# c# error: Use of unassigned local variable (context visual studio T4 ENGINE)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4

In C# (within the context of T4 template see http://www.olegsych.com/2008/03/how-to-generate-multiple-outputs-from-single-t4-template/) I want to do this

```
<# String myTemplateVar; 
#>

<# if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myTemplateVar)) { 
    myTemplateVar= "name";
}; 
#>
```

I want to give a value to myTemplateVar if myTemplateVar has not already been setup by an external call from T4 engine in another template which would have this instruction:

```
CallContext.SetData("myTemplate.myTemplateVar", ExternalTemplateVar);
```

But I cannot even compile in C# why ? How to fix this ?

This kind of stuff is easy to do in PHP I don't understand why in C# it seems so complicated.

Update: the problem is that if I initialize to either Null or Empty to avoid compilation error, how can I detect that the variable has been setup by an external call ?

Comment: C# requires all variables declared to have a value before you use them. In your case, the C# compiler can't know that you intend to set it from outside. Default the variable to an empty string or null and it should work.

Comment: Hi there. It would be helpful if you gave a little more detail on how the other template is combined with this one. Is it included inbetween the two blocks you show above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The myTemplateVar variable as defined above is at method scope inside the class underlying the template (inside the TransformText method).If you'd like a class-level, then you could use a class feature block, like so.

```
<#+ public string myTemplateVar; #>
```

or even a class static:

```
<#+ public static string myTemplateVar; #>
```

However, there's still no way to tell whether the variable has been set, other than by its null value or not though for a reference type in C#.

Comment: That's really a pity. I will have to give up T4 and try to find another template engine. T4 really not flexible.

Comment: You could use null vs empty string, if empty string is not a valid value for your scenario or indeed some other magic string.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<# String myTemplateVar = String.Empty;  #>
```

in order to resolve the compile error.

Comment: the problem is that if I initialize to either Null or Empty to avoid compilation error, how can I detect that the variable has been setup by an external call ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving your string a default value? If it does not get in the if block, it will remain unassigned.

Comment: See my comment if I put a default value it defeats what I want to detect: external setting of the variable.

Comment: @user310291 Out of curiosity, the above is not in a function?